# Raw midi values and bytes c++

Tags: android, c++, midi, usb-otg

I use superpowered, I need send midi note to a controller midi.
The problem is that I saw a function `send(int deviceID, unsigned char *data, int bytes);`
Where in their source code say:

> deviceID: Device identifier.
>   data: Raw MIDI data.
>   bytes: Number of
>   bytes.

I don't know the values that I need put exactly on data and bytes to work.
 The raw midi could be `0x80 - 0x48 - 0x00`(start of C4 note, pitch= 72, [See values](http://www.music-software-development.com/midi-tutorial.html))
And the bytes `1001nnnn0kkkkkkk0kkkkkkk`(note on event [See values](https://www.midi.org/specifications-old/item/table-1-summary-of-midi-message)) for example?
Something like that:

> SuperpoweredUSBMIDI::send(deviceID, reinterpret_cast(0x80 - 0x48 - 0x00), 1001nnnn0kkkkkkk0kkkkkkk);

The problem that always crash, and I can't debug or get the error for the reason that I use the mobile with otg to replicate the error.
When I find a solution, I will put it as soon as I can.

I'm newbie with markdown, sorry for any mistakes and my English grammar.

**Edit:** I'm using the example project that they have on GitHub for testing purposes, specifically the simpleusb project. ([source](https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-iOS-Linux-Windows-tvOS-macOS-Interactive-Audio-Platform/tree/master/Examples_Android/SuperpoweredUSBExample/simpleusb))

I make a small modifications and work, but with this specifically I try with many ways and nothing. I think this simple macrochange at least could work if I insert well the values
class **simpleusb.cpp**:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <SuperpoweredCPU.h>
#include <AndroidIO/SuperpoweredUSBAudio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// Called when the application is initialized. You can initialize SuperpoweredUSBSystem
// at any time btw. Although this function is marked __unused, it's due Android Studio's
// annoying warning only. It's definitely used.
__unused jint JNI_OnLoad (
        JavaVM * __unused vm,
        void * __unused reserved
) {
    SuperpoweredUSBSystem::initialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

// Called when the application is closed. You can destroy SuperpoweredUSBSystem at any time btw.
// Although this function is marked __unused, it's due Android Studio's annoying warning only.
// It's definitely used.
__unused void JNI_OnUnload (
        JavaVM * __unused vm,
        void * __unused reserved
) {
    SuperpoweredUSBSystem::destroy();
}

// A helper structure for sine wave output.
typedef struct sineWaveOutput {
    float mul;
    unsigned int step;
} sineWaveOutput;

// This is called periodically for audio I/O. Audio is always 32-bit floating point,
// regardless of the bit depth preference. (SuperpoweredUSBAudioProcessingCallback)
static bool audioProcessing (
        void *clientdata,
        int __unused deviceID,
        float *audioIO,
        int numberOfSamples,
        int samplerate,
        int __unused numInputChannels,
        int numOutputChannels
) {
    // If audioIO is NULL, then it's the very last call, IO is closing.
    if (!audioIO) {
        // Free memory for sine wave struct.
        free(clientdata);
        return true;
    }
    sineWaveOutput *swo = (sineWaveOutput *)clientdata;
    if (swo->mul == 0.0f) swo->mul = (2.0f * float(M_PI) * 300.0f) / float(samplerate);

    // Output sine wave on all output channels.
    for (int n = 0; n < numberOfSamples; n++) {
        float v = sinf(swo->step++ * swo->mul) * 0.5f;
        for (int c = 0; c < numOutputChannels; c++) *audioIO++ = v;
    }

    return true; // Return false for silence, true if we put audio output into audioIO.
}

static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static int latestMidiCommand = -1;
static int latestMidiChannel = 0;
static int latestMidiNumber = 0;
static int latestMidiValue = 0;

// This is called when some MIDI data is coming in.
// We are doing some primitive MIDI data processing here.
static void onMidiReceived (
        void * __unused clientdata,
        int __unused deviceID,
        unsigned char *data,
        int bytes
) {
    while (bytes > 0) {
        if (*data > 127) {
            int command = *data >> 4;
            switch (command) {
                case 8: // note off
                case 9: // note on
                case 11: // control change
                    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
                    // store incoming MIDI data
                    latestMidiCommand = command;
                    latestMidiChannel = *data++ & 15;
                    latestMidiNumber = *data++;
                    latestMidiValue = *data++;
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                    bytes -= 3;
                    break;
                default:
                    data++;
                    bytes--;
            }
        } else {
            data++;
            bytes--;
        }
    }
}

// Beautifying the ugly Java-C++ bridge (JNI) with these macros.
#define PID com_superpowered_simpleusb_SuperpoweredUSBAudio // Java package name and class name. Don't forget to update when you copy this code.
#define MAKE_JNI_FUNCTION(r, n, p) extern "C" JNIEXPORT r JNICALL Java_ ## p ## _ ## n
#define JNI(r, n, p) MAKE_JNI_FUNCTION(r, n, p)

// This is called by the SuperpoweredUSBAudio Java object when a USB device is connected.
JNI(jint, onConnect, PID) (
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject __unused obj,
        jint deviceID,
        jint fd,
        jbyteArray rawDescriptor
) {
    jbyte *rd = env->GetByteArrayElements(rawDescriptor, NULL);
    int dataBytes = env->GetArrayLength(rawDescriptor);
    int r = SuperpoweredUSBSystem::onConnect(deviceID, fd, (unsigned char *)rd, dataBytes);
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(rawDescriptor, rd, JNI_ABORT);

    // r is 0 if SuperpoweredUSBSystem can't do anything with the connected device.
    // r & 2 is true if the device has MIDI. Start receiving events.
    if (r & 2) {
        SuperpoweredUSBMIDI::startIO(deviceID, NULL, onMidiReceived);


//TODO HERE IT'S THE PROBLEM: error: integer literal is too large to be represented in any integer type
        SuperpoweredUSBMIDI::send(deviceID, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(0x80 - 0x48 - 0x00), 100100010011100000000011);
//FINISH PROBLEM






    }

    // r & 1 is true if the device has audio. Start output.
    if (r & 1) {
        // allocate struct for sine wave oscillator
        sineWaveOutput *swo = (sineWaveOutput *)malloc(sizeof(sineWaveOutput));
        if (swo) {
            swo->mul = 0.0f;
            swo->step = 0;
            SuperpoweredCPU::setSustainedPerformanceMode(true);

            // Our preferred settings: 44100 Hz, 16 bits, 0 input channels, 256 output channels,
            // low latency. Superpowered will set up the audio device as close as it can to these.
            SuperpoweredUSBAudio::easyIO (
                    deviceID,                    // deviceID
                    44100,                       // sampling rate
                    16,                          // bits per sample
                    0,                           // numInputChannels
                    256,                         // numOutputChannels
                    SuperpoweredUSBLatency_Low,  // latency
                    swo,                         // clientData
                    audioProcessing              // SuperpoweredUSBAudioProcessingCallback
            );
        }
    }
    return r;
}

// This is called by the SuperpoweredUSBAudio Java object when a USB device is disconnected.
JNI(void, onDisconnect, PID) (
        JNIEnv * __unused env,
        jobject __unused obj,
        jint deviceID
) {
    SuperpoweredUSBSystem::onDisconnect(deviceID);
    SuperpoweredCPU::setSustainedPerformanceMode(false);
}

#undef PID
#define PID com_superpowered_simpleusb_MainActivity

// This is called by the MainActivity Java object periodically.
JNI(jintArray, getLatestMidiMessage, PID) (
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject __unused obj
) {
    jintArray ints = env->NewIntArray(4);
        jint *i = env->GetIntArrayElements(ints, 0);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    i[0] = latestMidiCommand;
    i[1] = latestMidiChannel;
    i[2] = latestMidiNumber;
    i[3] = latestMidiValue;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(ints, i, 0);
    return ints;
}
```

The other important class but I don't change on this problem, **MainActivity**:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SuperpoweredUSBAudioHandler {

    private Handler handler;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.text);



        SuperpoweredUSBAudio usbAudio = new SuperpoweredUSBAudio(getApplicationContext(), this);
        usbAudio.check();

        // Update UI every 40 ms.
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int[] midi = getLatestMidiMessage();
                switch (midi[0]) {
                    case 8: textView.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "Note Off, CH %d, %d, %d",
                            midi[1] + 1, midi[2], midi[3]));




                            break;
                    case 9: textView.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "Note On, CH %d, %d, %d",
                            midi[1] + 1, midi[2], midi[3]));





                            break;
                    case 11: textView.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "Control Change, CH %d, %d, %d",
                            midi[1] + 1, midi[2], midi[3]));
                            break;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 40);
            }
        };
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 40);

/*Not look, only for testing purposes and for remember what use.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
        int numBytes = 0;
        int channel = 6; // MIDI channels 1-16 are encoded as 0-15.
        buffer[numBytes++] = (byte)(0x90 + (channel - 1)); // note on
        buffer[numBytes++] = (byte)60; // pitch is middle C
        buffer[numBytes++] = (byte)127; // max velocity
        int offset = 0;*/

    }

    public void onUSBAudioDeviceAttached(int deviceIdentifier) {
    }

    public void onUSBMIDIDeviceAttached(int deviceIdentifier) {
    }

    public void onUSBDeviceDetached(int deviceIdentifier) {
    }

    // Function implemented in the native library.
    private native int[] getLatestMidiMessage();



    static {
        System.loadLibrary("SuperpoweredExample");
    }






}
```

**Error** that I can't build app finally:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process D:\Users\ramoc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build F:\PROYECTOFIN\SuperpoweredUSBExample\simpleusb\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a --target SuperpoweredExample}
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SuperpoweredExample.dir/simpleusb.cpp.o
FAILED: D:\Users\ramoc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=aarch64-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=D:/Users/ramoc/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=D:/Users/ramoc/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot  -DSuperpoweredExample_EXPORTS -IF:/PROYECTOFIN/SuperpoweredUSBExample/simpleusb/src/main/jni/src/main/jni -IF:/PROYECTOFIN/SuperpoweredUSBExample/simpleusb/../../../Superpowered -isystem D:/Users/ramoc/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem D:/Users/ramoc/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/arm64-v8a/include -isystem D:/Users/ramoc/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -isystem D:/Users/ramoc/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -fsigned-char -IF:\PROYECTOFIN\SuperpoweredUSBExample\simpleusb\..\..\..\Superpowered -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/SuperpoweredExample.dir/simpleusb.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles\SuperpoweredExample.dir\simpleusb.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/SuperpoweredExample.dir/simpleusb.cpp.o -c F:\PROYECTOFIN\SuperpoweredUSBExample\simpleusb\src\main\jni\simpleusb.cpp
F:\PROYECTOFIN\SuperpoweredUSBExample\simpleusb\src\main\jni\simpleusb.cpp:129:100: error: integer literal is too large to be represented in any integer type
        SuperpoweredUSBMIDI::send(deviceID, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(0x80 - 0x48 - 0x00), 100100010011100000000011);
                                                                                                   ^
F:\PROYECTOFIN\SuperpoweredUSBExample\simpleusb\src\main\jni\simpleusb.cpp:129:100: warning: implicit conversion from 'unsigned long long' to 'int' changes value from 7976667151972931595 to 887068683 [-Wconstant-conversion]
        SuperpoweredUSBMIDI::send(deviceID, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(0x80 - 0x48 - 0x00), 100100010011100000000011);
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Maybe it's for the documentation, very newbie with jni or too complex to me for now to understand 100%.

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: Edited... I'm sorry for being late

Comment: What exactly crashes? There is no `send()` call in the code.

Comment: With the edit and being like this now, I can't build the app and say the error mentioned above, I put now all error build best.  
And if I'm not mistaken, when r & 2 it's true, it runs, in my case when the app runs, I put a midi device only (launchpad), detects it and immediately send the midi note to the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so here's what `send` is saying:

```
send(int deviceID, unsigned char *data, int bytes);
```

Send to `deviceId` a pointer to a buffer called `data` that has a certain number of `bytes`.

So when you say:
    SuperpoweredUSBMIDI::send(deviceID, reinterpret_cast(0x80 - 0x48 - 0x00), 100100010011100000000011);

What you are essentially saying is "subtract these 3 numbers: `0x80 - 0x48 - 0x00`", then re-interpret that number as a pointer to a buffer somewhere in memory.  That buffer in memory contains `100100010011100000000011` bytes of data that I want you to read.

To fix this, we would send the data like this:

```
unsigned char* send_buffer[32] = {0}; // zero out buffer to use as scratch
send_buffer[0] = 0x90;
send_buffer[1] = 0x48;
send_buffer[2] = 0x00;

SuperpoweredUSBMIDI::send(deviceID, send_buffer, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, tomorrow I'll try it, but now I understand it better

Comment: Finally the app run, but I try it and the device don't get the midi value (no leds)
I put a button for test the send midi and nothing. Don't worry and thanks (: , maybe it's other issue, because your explanation is very good

Answer (score 0):

i thought midi had a check sum value (byte) appended to the sequence - is that done in your code or in the library code?

the message should be an array of unsigned char and pass the address of the array (name)
well that's what id have done in C when I was programming midi.